# How to generate fragment url in controller

Tags: symfony, esi

I looking for possible to generate fragment url without use twig

in twig i can use

```
{{ render_hinclude(controller(' 
{{ render_esi(controller('
```

i see twig extensions but all is not public , protected ...

how to generate this path in controller ?

I have controller name and parameters that i want to send - need url for fragment render

UPDATE 1 - $router->generate() is not same as fragment url

example fragment url is:

```
/_fragment?_hash=Wnx0PaTAT7XiwB0C3O92GtOfCeHogDYDgCwE9%2Bn9F%2F0%3D&_path=jobId%3D206%26_sonata_admin%3Dadmin.job.product%26pathInfo%3D%252Fjob%252F206%252Fedit%26_format%3Dhtml%26_locale%3Dpl%26_controller%3DApp%255CController%255CProductCrudController%253A%253AjobListAction
```

is for esi / hinclude

Comment: no fragment url is not classic url

Comment: Then what do you mean with "url fragment"? Can you provide an example

Comment: I add example url generated for fragment assess